# Send eth to multiple addresses

Tags: web3js

I need to send eth to accounts that have erc20 tokens:

```
foreth.forEach(function(item,i){
    const balance = contractInstance.methods.balanceOf(item).call(function(err, result) {
       console.log(result)
    if (result>0) {
    console.log("success")
    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress)
  .then((count) => {
    let rawTransaction = {
      'from': fromAddress,
      'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(10 * 1e9),
      'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(21000),
      'to': item,
      'value': web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("0.0002")),
      'nonce': web3.utils.toHex(count)+i
    }
    let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)
    transaction.sign(privateKey)
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
      .on('transactionHash', console.log)

  })




    }
    })
    })
```

But when executing the code, 2 caches are generated for me, which are not on etherscan. Account transactions are also not visible, what's the problem?
Some later i get error:

```
Transaction was not mined w
ithin 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware
 that it might still be mined!
```

any1 can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clearly identify what you are trying to achieve.

- A proper indentation will help people here to help you.
- `function(item,i)`, perhaps `function(recipient,i)` would be more informative.
- It is clunky to mix callbacks and promises. If you want to use only promises, my advice, then do:

  ```
  const balance = await contractInstance.methods.balanceOf(item).call();
  ```

  Of course this means you have to make `async function(item,i)`.
- Why do you limit the gas: `'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(21000)`? Are you sure that none of the recipients are contracts that need a bit more?
- Are you sure that your hard-coded gas price `'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(10 * 1e9),` is consistent with the going rate?
- What do you think `web3.utils.toHex(count)+i` achieves? Would `web3.utils.toHex(count+i)` not make more sense?
- And, most importantly, you are doing `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress)` inside the loop. You do understand that this number can change if a previous transaction is mined while the loop is running. When this happens, there will be a nonce at which there is no transaction. The transaction with nonces above the missing one will not be mined as long as a tx with the missing nonce is emitted. You have to fetch this number before you enter the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! My mistakes are related to my inexperience in this direction, I will try to correct it. Could you tell me what values should be in the variables gasprice and gaslimit in my case?

Comment: You can ask the gas price from web3, and you can estimateGas needed.